# EF Exception Message for Duplicate Key does not get values updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I run a bulk update using EF db.savechanges() and it is very common to have duplicate values on my table.

To show the user that the value was not update because of a duplicate key on the table, I have a try/catch that stores the values on a datatable along with the exception value through code:

```
output.Rows.Add(item.Tracking_id,"Not loaded because: " + ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
```

It does work and the exception message is stored on my datatable correctly.

The thing not working as expected is that the exception message is not updating with each iteration. The Message is:

> "Duplicate entry 'Current foreach Item' for key 'PRIMARY'"

The current foreach item (tracking_id) takes like 3 to 4 iterations to change on the exception message. While I am testing, the current item is indeed duplicate, but the message does not reflect the current item.

I checked the exception stack and all values in it, but the only place with the message informing the duplicate item is at ex.InnerException.InnerException, other than that I do not get the value of the duplicate item.

Is this an expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, I am changing this to first check on the DB if the entry already exists, just curious about the try/catch problem

Comment: have you tried some logging? within your iteration?

Comment: I fear that I am uncertain of what you mean. If by logging you mean to store on a individual variable the values of the current tracking id and the exceptions and look them one by one, then yes. The iteration goes smoothly.